# Getting no response from the server when posting request through POSTMAN

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, windows-10

When sending this request, we are getting no response but below:
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://0.0.0.0:3000/projectname/api

Postman console log shows that:

Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 0.0.0.0:3000

## Troubleshooting:

1. In settings, we have turned of SSl certificate verification
2. Have increased the request timeout value significantly upto 90
3. Turned of "Automatically follow redirects"
4. Have kept CA cert turned off.
5. In proxy tab, We have once kept global proxy off and system proxy on, followed by reverse. Also, kept both the proxy off. 
   While we kept global proxy ON, we kept proxy server as 0.0.0.0 and port number as 3000, i.e. the i.p./port flask server is running.
6. In "Capture API request with postman" tab, under filter tab, selected method as POST and in "url does not contain" field put
7. Turned off firewall, defender, and other antivirus programs in system

After trying with all this options individually, we have tried out sending request through POSTMAN. But everytime, we have hit the same error as 
"Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://0.0.0.0:3000/projectname/api"

The same configuration is working fine in linux environment, but when i am trying this out in windows-10,windows-7 , then hitting this issue. I need to solve this issue in windows and please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address to connect to.
You should try "http://localhost:3000/projectname/api" or use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address you can connect to, try connecting to 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead.

[More info about 0.0.0.0 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

> [Uses include] A way to specify "any IPv4 address at all". It is used in this way when configuring servers (i.e. when binding listening sockets).

[Possibly your linux setup converts 0.0.0.0 to localhost](https://superuser.com/a/536198/573288)